# awk: print first line of file before reading lines

Tags: bash, awk

How would I go about printing the first line of given input before I start stepping through each of the lines with awk?

Say I wanted to run the command `ps aux` and return the column headings and a particular pattern I'm searching for. In the past I've done this:

```
ps aux | ggrep -Pi 'CPU|foo'
```

Where `CPU` is a value I know will be in the first line of input as it's one of the column headings and `foo` is the particular pattern I'm actually searching for.

I found an awk pattern that will pull the first line:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { exit }; 1'
```

Which makes sense, but I can't seem to figure out how to fire this before I do my pattern matching on the rest of the input. I thought I could put it in the `BEGIN` section of the awk command but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: thats wrong with grep? It maskes much more sense for this task than the awk one.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. if awk read your 1st line, it has already started reading lines of your file.

Comment: @hek2mgl, the issue I run into when grepping is when the column header I'm using for the match happens to be in some of the output aside from the first line, e.g. if I grep for `PID` to get the header sometimes it returns process lines with the pattern `pid` in them if I grep with the `-i` flag. Also, I'm trying to learn more about awk in general. @Kent, What I want is output from awk that always contains the first line and then also contains the rest of the lines that match the pattern I'm matching for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following awk script:

```
ps aux | awk 'NR == 1 || /PATTERN/'
```

it prints the current line either if it is the first line in output or if it contains the pattern.

Btw, the same result could be achieved using `sed`:

```
ps aux | sed -n '1p;/PATTERN/p'
```

Comment: Simple solution. I think you can drop the two `.*` -- they just add clutter

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Yeah, this was really unnecessary clutter. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 7):

If you want to read in the first line in the `BEGIN` action, you can read it in with `getline`, process it, and discard that line before moving on to the rest of your awk command. This is "stepping in", but may be helpful if you're parsing a header or something first.

```
#input.txt
Name    City
Megan   Detroit
Jackson Phoenix
Pablo   Charlotte

awk 'BEGIN { getline; col1=$1; col2=$2; } { print col1, $1; print col2, $2 }' input.txt

# output
Name Megan
City Detroit
Name Jackson
City Phoenix
Name Pablo
City Charlotte
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explaining awk `BEGIN`**

> I thought I could put it in the BEGIN section ...

In `awk`, you can have more than one `BEGIN` clause. These are executed *in order* **before** awk starts to read from `stdin`.

Comment: I don't get why you mentioning the `BEGIN` clause in this case. Can you elaborate on this? (seems that I'm missing something)

Comment: I've quoted the phrase that triggered this response now.  And that was all that this question was about.  Your answer deals with the core issue.